# Probability and independence (joint PMF)

Tags: probability

Given a joint PMF, if I wanted to see if X and (Y - X) are independent, do I check:

$F_{x,(y-x)} = F_x{(x)} * F_y{(y-x)}$?
This is just my understanding given what I've found on wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#For_random_variables

Comment: in your equation of densities you should have written:
$F_{y-x}(y-x)$ instead of $F_{y}(y-x)$. the density $F_{y-x}(z)$ is a convolution of $F_{y}(y)$ and $F_{x}(x)$

Answer (score 2):

$X$ and $Y-X$ are independent (discrete) random variables if and only if for *each* pair of real numbers $(u,v)$, 
$P\{X=u, Y-X=v\}$ *equals* $P\{X=u\}P\{Y-X = v\}$
Note that 
$$P\{X=u, Y-X=v\} =  P\{X=u, Y=u+v\} = p_{X,Y}(u,u+v)$$
can be read off from the joint probability mass function of $X$ and $Y$ while
$$P\{X=u\} = \sum_{t} p_{X,Y}(u,t)$$ requires just a little more work in computing
the sum,
and $$P\{Y-X=v\} = \sum_t P\{Y=t, X=t-v\} = \sum_t p_{X,Y}(t-v,t)$$
is yet another sum you need to find.

All this for just $(u,v)$. Then repeat for other $(u,v)$. Note that if
$u$ is *not* a value that $X$ takes on, that is, $P\{X=u\}=0$, then
$P\{X=u, Y-X=v\} = 0$ also (think why!) and so
$$P\{X=u, Y-X=v\} = 0 = P\{X=u\}P\{Y-X = v\}$$
and you can skip all the above calculations.